# uninstall utorrent, installed the 64bit on 32bit

Tags: 32-bit, utorrent

i am new to ubuntu, Just recently installed torrent using [this link](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/install-utorrent-in-ubuntu-fedora/).

Problem is i mistakenly downloaded the 64bit and after installing it i found out my OS is 32bit,

As After going all those steps i get a error message :

```
No Command 'utserver' found, did you mean: *********
```

I am not sure how to roll back all the steps i did installing the utorrent, without corrupting my Operating System so that i can install 32bit utorrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the steps used, you just have to remove two things:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/bin/utserver /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

That's the link you created to the `utorrent` program and the directory in which you installed `utorrent`.